# Difference between MemoryError and OSError with errno 12 "Cannot allocate memory"?

Tags: python, exception, memory, out-of-memory

Sometimes, bits of my code fail raising a [`MemoryError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError).  At other times, they fail with [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) with [`ENOMEM`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html#errno.ENOMEM) (`OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory`).  What is the difference between Python raising a `MemoryError` and Python raising an `OSError` with `Cannot allocate memory`?